# How to fix Segmentation fault in C in hash table with linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, hashtable

I'm coding a hash table that maps strings to integers which has and array with pointers to nodes of a linked list. It appears that I'm getting a segmentation fault in the set value method where I'm comparing the strings to see if a specific key is already in the hash table.

```
typedef struct _node
{
    char *key;
    int value;
    struct _node *next; /* pointer to the next node in the list */
} node;

/*
 * Declaration of the hash table struct.
 * 'slot' is an array of node pointers, so it's a pointer to a pointer.
 */

typedef struct
{
    node **slot;
} hash_table;


int hash(char *s)
{
    int sum, size, i;
    sum = 0;
    size = strlen(s);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += (int) s[i];
    }
    return (sum % SIZE_ARRAY);
}


node *create_node(char *key, int value)
{
    node *result = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (result == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: out of memory. "
                "Terminating program.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    result->key = key;
    result->value = value;
    result->next = NULL;

    return result;
}

/* Create a new hash table. */
hash_table *create_hash_table()
{
    hash_table *table = (hash_table *)malloc(sizeof(hash_table));
    if (table == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: out of memory. "
                "Terminating program.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    table->slot = (node **)calloc(SIZE_ARRAY, sizeof(node *));
    if (table->slot == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: out of memory. "
                "Terminating program.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return table;
}

void set_value(hash_table *ht, char *key, int value)
{
    int indx = hash(key);
    int found = 0;
    node *new_node;
    node *list = ht->slot[indx];
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(list->key, key) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            list->value = value;
        }
        list++;
    }
    if (found == 0)
    {
        new_node = create_node(key, value);
        new_node->next = ht->slot[indx];
        ht->slot[indx] = new_node;
    }
}
```

I used gdp to try and debug, and it seems like the error comes from the line "if (strcmp(list->key, key) == 0)", I think it might have something to do with the pointers but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post the code for `hash` and your `struct` definitions. What line is failing? At a guess, `hash` is returning a value that is greater than `SIZE_ARRAY`. So, consider: `int indx = hash(key) % SIZE_ARRAY;`

Comment: The `list++` in your `while` loop is wrong. You want: `list = list->next` And, in that loop, under the `if` you want a `break;` after `list->value = value;`

Comment: Craig, post that as an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

The `list++` in your `while` loop is wrong. You want: `list = list->next` And, in that loop, under the `if` you want a `break;` after `list->value = value;`

You don't really need `found` as you can hook off `list`.

Here's some refactored code:

```
void
set_value(hash_table * ht, char *key, int value)
{
    int indx = hash(key);
    node *new_node;
    node *list = ht->slot[indx];

    while (list != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(list->key, key) == 0) {
            list->value = value;
            break;
        }
        list = list->next;
    }

    if (list == NULL) {
        new_node = create_node(key, value);
        new_node->next = ht->slot[indx];
        ht->slot[indx] = new_node;
    }
}
```